# NLog. Write logs into different tables

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, database, logging, nlog

I have a ASP MVC project with areas and i have to log exceptions into database. But I have a problem. I must write log exceptions from each area to its own table in database. I have an idea to configure `DataTargets` for all areas with `CommandText` related with table name, but it seems pretty ugly. A bit more fantastic way is to get all areas on application start and build targets via some factory.

Does someone have any idea or best practices about this issue?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `CommandText` property of the database target is a layout, so you could do:

```
<target xsi:type="Database"
      name="db"
      commandText="insert into ${event-properties:tablename} ... ">
```

and using fluent style (NLog.Fluent namespace):

```
logger.Info().Message("this is a message").Property("tablename", "table1").Write();
```

You could also use more global contexts, like GDC, MDC etc. See [NLog Wiki](https://github.com/nlog/nlog/wiki/Gdc-Layout-Renderer)